# How can I access the selected value when bind a change event using knockout JS in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

**Knockout Template**

```
<select data-bind="event:{ change: permissionChanged}">
    <option data-bind="i18n: 'Yes', value: 'yes'"></option>
    <option data-bind="i18n: 'No', value: 'no'"></option>
</select>
```

**Js Function**

```
permissionChanged: function(obj, event){
    console.log('value Changed');
},
```

So basically I want to access the **value** when the end-user changes the value on the **select** element.

Currently when the user changes the value in the dropdown then the function is called but I want value there.

Your help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Added answer let me know if it's helpful or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this below code :

```
console.log(event.target.value);
```

Comment: Thanks :) @Rohan

Comment: Mark as upvote and accept answer if it's useful.